# How to use pointer as a model in querying in gorm database

Tags: postgresql, go

ENVIRONTMENT

ORM: `github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.16`
Go: `1.19`
Database: `Postgresql` 
OS: `macOS Monterey 12.5`

I created this service

```
func (s *service) FindByID(ctx *gin.Context, id string) (*ModelName, error) {
    var model *ModelName

    err := config.DB.Where(`"id" = ?`, id).First(&model).Error

    if nil != err {
        return nil, err
    }

    return model, nil
}
```

But if I run that code, it will return the error `unsupported destination, should be slice or struct`. That only happens when I'm using `github.com/jinzhu/gorm`, if I changed that to `gorm.io/gorm`, it will work fine.

I still want to use `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` but I also want to be able to return `nil` if the there is an error, that can only work if I'm using a pointer.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't what indicated on the [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html) that's to say use var model ModelName instead of var model *ModelName?